# Facebook error on product detail page(use Send to messenger plugin)

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am consistently getting this error on the product detail page (error in the JS console):

```
ErrorUtils caught an error:
"<![EX[["Bootloader: %s is not in the component map","GeneratedArtilleryUserTi...". Subsequent errors won't be logged; see fburl.com/debugjs .reportError @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:57
applyWithGuard @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:57
d @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:102
B @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:38
applyWithGuard @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:57
B @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:38
z @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:38
I @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:38
M @ mO2eGwfpUvV.js:38
(anonymous) @ feedback.php?    api_key=227929537971343&channel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FoVjM2wVZ10b.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df27a838fb6ccc4c%26domain%3Dwww.thechipwitch.com%26origin%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.thechipwitch.com%2Ff20ffc0b0fdae08%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thechipwitch.com%2Fkits%2Fprotection%2Fprot-tech-support&locale=en_US&numposts=10&sdk=joey&width=600:17
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

facebook sdk api is down for last 18h or so => https://developers.facebook.com/status/dashboard/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I got the code from developers.facebook.com to insert a page plugin on our website...

Here is the code I got from Facebook

insider Header

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the following snippet for displaying the page plugin

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/picobello8193" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false">
    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/picobello8193" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/picobello8193">Picobello Schönes für Kinder</a>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```